# Is there a way to PERMANENTLY disable colour in my phone?

Tags: adb, accessibility, developer-options, overlay, color

The phone in question is Samsung s21 Fe.

I find I am much more productive when my phone is monochrome however I always find myself turning monochrome off without realising and productivity suffers until I catch myself.

Is there a way to make my phone permanently greyscale? I realise I'm better off without any colour on my phone and if I really need to see something in colour I will use my PC.

I notice there are many ways to turn monochrome on/off (accessibility, developer options, quick shortcuts) so I don't think a password will work.

Can adb or rooting turn off colour mode completely? Can I open up my phone and physically destroy parts of my phone responsible for colour while having an otherwise fully functioning phone?

Comment: I don't think there is any "permanent" method of disabling color on the device... any hardware attempt would likely destroy the device as color isn't an "added" in thing, it is integral in the display... Honestly, an LED panel is kind of emulating a monochrome display with color, but your eyes don't see it that way. But I mean once you set it in accessibility settings, I'm not sure why it would turn off at random.